# Mysql Display data Month wise

Tags: mysql

It is my query to fetch month wise data but this query is showing the same data of october in november column, there is no data in november column i want to show it as empty. Why November is showing october data? i attach pic of these tables and result.
[Result of this query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/65YUv.png)

[Tables Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTIs7.png)

```
SELECT 
(SELECT products.pro_id) AS id,
(SELECT products.product_name) AS Pro_Name,
(SELECT products.nsp) AS NSP,
(SELECT SUM(orders.current_sales) WHERE YEAR(orders.order_date) =2017 AND MONTH(orders.order_date) =10) AS October,
(SELECT SUM(orders.current_sales) WHERE YEAR(orders.order_date) =2017 AND MONTH(orders.order_date) =11) AS November
FROM products, orders
GROUP BY id, orders.order_date
```

Comment: Please provide the tables structures and example data on a sqlfiddle (http://www,sqlfiddle.com).. PHPMyAdmin has a very easy to use export function.

Comment: Besides your SQL has a smell.. Using SELECT in columns where you don't have to use SELECT. Cartesian product or a CROSS JOIN.. Making use off a invalid GROUP BY

Comment: @Raymond Nijland i added sql fiddle

Answer (score 0):

My guess, from \looking at the query you posted, is that you are seeing a Cartesian product result. You don't have a join statement between the two tables, resulting in a Cartesian product.

Add a join and I'll bet that fixes it.

Correction: After looking more at your query, I don't understand what you are doing. That query is unlike anything I've ever seen. Subselects for each of the group by columns?

Comment: i Applied left join, but still it is showing the result of october in november

Comment: Your query needs more than a left join. The whole query is incorrect and needs to be rewritten.

Comment: You posted a picture of your data and none of those rows have a November date. Despite all my experience in sql, I cannot figure out what your query is doing or why it gives you a November value. Did you post the right data picture? Did you post your actual query?

Comment: Yes there is no record in november. Only 2017-10-12 has records

Comment: I added SQLFiddle

Comment: @user3030814 Is there a link to the fiddle?

Comment: it is the link of jsFidle

Comment: Are you absolutely sure the query in your question is the one you ran? In the fiddle, it returns an error that says "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE YEAR(orders.order_date) =2017 AND MONTH(orders.order_date) =10) AS October' at line 5
". And like I said in an earlier comment, the sql in your question is very foreign to me and I've been working with relational databases a long time. Does the sql run for you in the fiddle?

Comment: Yes it is 100% working i tried many times. but it is not working on SQLFiddle i m also amazed. The same query i copied. But if there any mistake can u suggest me any better?

Comment: i m using xampp v3.2.2 is there any difference?